# Adding a button or link after every parent node in tree view

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a tree view which is populating parent , child and grand child node correctly like this.

```
-Root 1
  |
  |___________ Child 1
  |___________ Child 2
  |___________ Child 3

- Root 2
  |___________ Child A
  |___________ Child B
  |               |___________ Grand Child 1
  |               |___________ Grand Child 2
  |
  |___________ Child C
```

Now I actually want a Create button / link after every parent node , to create a new child or grand child element.

```
-Root 1
  |___ **Create New Child**
  |
  |___________ Child 1
  |___________ Child 2
  |___________ Child 3

- Root 2
  |____ **Create New Child**
  |__________ Child A
  |___________ Child B
  |               |__ **Create New Child**
  |               |________ Grand Child 1
  |               |___________ Grand Child 2
  |
  |___________ Child C
```

So that when I click on Create New Child it opens a blank form where I can fill info and create a new child , right now I can edit node info by click on any node.

Here is my code to create node.

```
 #region ROOT NODE

        DataTable dtInstitute = dsResult.Tables[0]; //dsResult contains two columns refValues, refGroupId , I have separate code for that

        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dtInstitute.Rows)
        {
            TreeNode child = new TreeNode
            {
                Text = row["refValues"].ToString(),
                Value = row["refGroupId"].ToString()
            };

            AddChild(child);
            treeCatalogManager.Nodes.Add(child);
        }

        treeCatalogManager.CollapseAll();

 #endregion


  private void AddChild(TreeNode child)
    {
        #region ADD CHILD

        DataTable dtChild = dsChildResult.Tables[0];    //dsChildResult contains two columns refValues, refGroupId , I have separate code for that and able to populate here        

        foreach (DataRow row in dtChild.Rows)
        {
            TreeNode nChild = new TreeNode
            {
                Text = row["refValues"].ToString(),
                Value = row["refGroupId"].ToString()
            };

            AddChild(nChild);
            child.ChildNodes.Add(nChild);

        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: How about, before your foreach statements, check if dtChild.Rows and dtInstitute.Rows have 1 or more elements, and If so add a line of code there to add your "create new child" node.